# How to compare a value to several other values in one line in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, equality

Is there a better alternative to this expression in Kotlin: `a == b || a == c`

I'm looking for something like `a == b || c` or `a.equals(b, c)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the simplest way is with the `in` operator:

```
a in listOf(b, c)
```

you can include as many items as you want inside the list.

Comment: I wish there was native support for the patterns listed in the question which would remove the necessity of creating a list for such trivial cases.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `when` as

```
when(a){
    b,c -> println("match") // match either b or c
    else -> println("no match") // in case of no match
}
```

Additionally, you can use `in` with range like

```
when(number){
    100,200 -> println(" 100 or 200 ")
    in 1..5 -> println("in range") // between 1 - 5
    !in 6..10 -> println("not in range") // not between 6 - 10
    else -> println("no match")
}
```

You can also use multiple custom `enum` values as

```
// often used to represent API/process status etc
when(Status.ERROR){
    in listOf(Status.ERROR, Status.EXCEPTION) -> println("Something when wrong") 
    else -> println("Success")
}

enum class Status{
    SUCCESS, ERROR, EXCEPTION
}
```

Comment: the question is about a single result value, not a switch expression

Comment: `when` is powerful for this use case, can use `val result = when(a){
        b,c -> true
        else -> false
    }`

Comment: there is no need in such complexity for this use case

Comment: it's a matter of choice and use cases as in real world, things always get complex and my answer already has an example with `in` which is being used in later posted selected answer so I provided the info prior :)

Comment: It is as close to "native support for the patterns listed in the question" which you asked for in another comment as you can get.

Comment: I prefer this approach over `a in listOf(b, c)` because this approach does not create an unnecessary data structure.

Answer (score 7):

Another option (which I personally prefer) is to create an extension function:

```
fun Any.equalsAny(vararg values: Any): Boolean {
    return this in values
}
```

Usage example:

```
val result1 =  20.equalsAny(10, 20, 30)               // Returns true
val result2 =  "ABC".equalsAny(10, 20, 30, 99 , 178)  // Returns false
val result3 =  "ABC".equalsAny("ABC", "XYD", "123")   // Returns true
val result4 =  "ABC".equalsAny("xxx", "XYD", "123")   // Returns false
```

You can even mix types and it works perfectly:

```
val a = 1
val b = "10"
val c = true
val search = 999
val search2 = false
val result5 = search.equalsAny(a, b, c)               // Returns false
val result6 = search2.equalsAny(a, b, c, 872, false)  // Returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put the values in a list and use `any`:

```
listOf(b, c).any { it == a }
```

This becomes especially handy if you have a lot of values to compare to.

---

Just in case you need it for and too:

`a == b && a == c` would translate to `listOf(b, c).all { it == a }`

Answer (score -1):

I defined a few helper functions:

```
inline fun <T> T.isAnyOf(a: T, b: T) = this == a || this == b
inline fun <T> T.isAnyOf(a: T, b: T, c: T) = this == a || this == b || this == c

inline fun <T> T.isNotAnyOf(a: T, b: T) = !isAnyOf(a, b)
inline fun <T> T.isNotAnyOf(a: T, b: T, c: T) = !isAnyOf(a, b, c)
```

Which can be used like this:

```
if ("word".isAnyOf("list", "of", "words")) { ... }
```